# Please check linear congruence equation solution

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

#### Preface

At first I wanted to ask the community to solve the equation for me as I knew very little about modular arithmetic. But then I decided to try and found that this is a [linear congruence equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearCongruenceEquation.html) and found the material about it on the web and seems, that I solved it eventually.

Now I ask the community to check my solution.

#### Problem

Suppose, we have a sequence of numbers, defined by formula:

$a(i) = 5 + i \cdot 7 \mod 12$

```
| i    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
|------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+----+----+---|
| a(i) | 5 | 0 | 7 | 2 | 9 | 4 | 11| 6 | 1 | 8 | 3  | 10 | 5  |
```

Given a sequence element, find it's number:

$5 + x \cdot 7 \mod 12 = a$

$a \in $[0, 11], $x \in $[0, 11]

x = ?

#### My solution

GCD(7, 12) = 1, therefore the solution exists.

$x \cdot 7 = (a - 5) \mod 12$

$x = (a - 5) \cdot 7^{-1} \mod 12$

$7^{-1} \mod 12 = 7\;$ because $7 \cdot 7 \mod 12 = 1$ ($49 = 48 + 1 = 12 \cdot 4 + 1$)

So we have:

$x = (a - 5) \cdot 7 \mod 12$

#### Check of the solution correctness

a = 1 (x = 8):

$x = (1 - 5) \cdot 7 \mod 12 = (-4) \cdot 7 \mod 12 = -28 \mod 12 = 12\cdot (-3) + 8 = 8$ (correct)

a = 5 (x = 0):

$x = (5 - 5) \cdot 7 \mod 12 = 0 \mod 12 = 0$ (correct)

a = 3 (x = 10):

$x = (3 - 5) \cdot 7 \mod 12 = (-2) \cdot 7 \mod 12 = -14 \mod 12 = -24 + 10 \mod 12 = 10$ (correct)

So, the formula seems correct.

Comment: A tip on writing and solving: Instead of writing a sequences of formulas as A,B,C,D....  add some words especially saying what implies what, and stating the justification for any implication that may not be obvious. Also see which are "iff"" (if and only if)  If you have shown that  "A iff b iff C iif D"  then you have "A iff D"  . Of course  you check for errors and all those words make it a LOT easier to check but many students think that you should only go  "$A\implies B \implies C \implies D$" and then try to see whether  D implies A,  when  the chain of logic was reversible at each step.

Comment: @user254665 Can you suggest an improvement to my solution in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your query to my comment :  We have $\text{GCD}(7,12)=1$  so for all $p,q$ we have $$\text{[1]..........}p\equiv q \pmod{12}\text{  iff}$$ $$\  p.7\equiv q.7 \pmod{12}.$$ And $$ \text{[2]...........}7.7\equiv 1\pmod{12}.$$ Therefore,  $$5+x.7 \equiv a \pmod{12}\text{  iff}$$ $$ x.7\equiv a-5 \pmod{12}\text{   iff}$$ $$ x.7.7\equiv (a-5).7 \pmod{12} \text{(...by [1]),   iff}$$ $$ x.1\equiv (a-5).7\pmod{12}\text{...(by [2])}.$$ To check , work backwards from the last line. [BTW,the RHS of the last line can be simplified because $-35\equiv 1\pmod{12}]$.